# Setting up YOURLS url shortener on a Windows azure website

Tags: azure, yourls, azure-pack

I tried following [this article](http://rjdudley.com/hosting-your-own-url-shortener-with-yourls-azure-web-site-and-webmatrix/) to setup YOURLS url shortener on my website [outrika.com](http://outrika.com). The website is hosted on Windows azure and i have successfully setup custom domain for it. Also i have added all YOURL files to it and have updated the user/config.php file. The links are being created in my admin panel so the DB connection is working correctly. But when i open a shortlink then it redirect me to the homepage(outrika.com) instead of the actual long link. Is their customization required in the yourls-loader.php. Here's how my web.config file looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="YOURLS www" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.outrika\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://outrika.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="YOURLS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/yourls-loader.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```